# Trouble with composite metric composition

Tags: librato

I'm trying to create a simple composite of two metrics for a Big Number chart:

```
mean([
  series("metric.a", {}),
  series("metric.b", {})
])
```

But when I do I receive the following error. Is my syntax off?

```
Unable to execute composite: ["error": "Requested MD data from SD endpoint"].
```

Comment: are you adding this composite in a chart in a space?  It sounds like the space is a source based space.  You need to create a tag based space to use that composite.  OR you can swap out "{}" for "*" (need the quotes for the *)

Comment: ah thanks MBeale - adding the wildcard worked.